# Efficiently count all the combinations of numbers having a sum close to 0

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, performance

I have following pandas dataframe
df

```
column1 column2 list_numbers          sublist_column
x        y      [10,-6,1,-4]             
a        b      [1,3,7,-2]               
p        q      [6,2,-3,-3.2]
```

the sublist_column will contain the numbers from the column "list_numbers" that adds up to 0 (0.5 is a tolerance)
I have written following code.

```
def return_list(original_lst,target_sum,tolerance):
    memo=dict()
    sublist=[]
    for i, x in enumerate(original_lst):
    
        if memo_func(original_lst, i + 1, target_sum - x, memo,tolerance) > 0:
            sublist.append(x)
            target_sum -= x          
    return sublist  

def memo_func(original_lst, i, target_sum, memo,tolerance):
    
    if i >= len(original_lst):
        if target_sum <=tolerance and target_sum>=-tolerance:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    if (i, target_sum) not in memo:  
        c = memo_func(original_lst, i + 1, target_sum, memo,tolerance)
        c += memo_func(original_lst, i + 1, target_sum - original_lst[i], memo,tolerance)
        memo[(i, target_sum)] = c  
    return memo[(i, target_sum)]
```

Then I am using the "return_list" function on the "sublist_column" to populate the result.

```
target_sum = 0
tolerance=0.5

df['sublist_column']=df['list_numbers'].apply(lambda x: return_list(x,0,tolerance))
```

the following will be the resultant dataframe

```
column1 column2 list_numbers          sublist_column
x        y      [10,-6,1,-4]             [10,-6,-4]
a        b      [1,3,7,-2]               []
p        q      [6,2,-3,-3.2]            [6,-3,-3.2]  #sum is -0.2(within the tolerance)
```

This is giving me correct result but it's very slow(takes 2 hrs to run if i use spyder IDE), as my dataframe size has roughly 50,000 rows, and the length of some of the lists in the "list_numbers" column is more than 15.
The running time is particularly getting affected when the number of elements in the lists in the "list_numbers" column is greater than 15.
e.g following list is taking almost 15 minutes to process

```
[-1572.35,-76.16,-261.1,-7732.0,-1634.0,-52082.42,-3974.15,
-801.65,-30192.79,-671.98,-73.06,-47.72,57.96,-511.18,-391.87,-4145.0,-1008.61,
-17.53,-17.53,-1471.08,-119.26,-2269.7,-2709,-182939.59,-19.48,-516,-6875.75,-138770.16,-71.11,-295.84,-348.09,-3460.71,-704.01,-678,-632.15,-21478.76]
```

How can i significantly improve my running time?

Comment: You input take 0.4 ms to compute on my machine and 75% of the time is spent in the Pandas assignment of the result... Most of the remaining time is pent in the apply function... Pandas is slow to deal with objects like list, CPython is slow to compute objects too. Recursive calls are also slow. Using CPython and Pandas for this task is probably not the good tool. That being said, can you give an input that is slow? The source of slowdown may be different on your big dataset.

Comment: thanks for your response! As an example the following list is taking almost 3 minutes to process.
[-850.85,-856.05,-734.09,5549.63,77.59,-39.73,23.63,13.93,-6455.54,-417.07,176.72,-570.41,3621.89,-233.47,-471.54,-30.33,-941.49,-1014.6,1614.5]
what data structure can I use if the pandas are slow to process objects like list?or if there is any other efficient way of doing things

Comment: The best thing to do in this case is probably to use a native language like C or C++. If this function is a part of a bigger project that is relatively big, you can use Cython or Numba. Whatever the solution, you need to use a different data structure. An efficient one is a big array containing all the array concatenated together and another one specifying the start-end slices. Note that this is more complex to use than in your current case but I expect a huge performance improvement.

Comment: Note that if you massively use Pandas for other things, a cheat can be to put the start-end slices in the dataframe and store the big flatten array outside the dataframe. You can then use Numba/Cython to efficiently compute the solution of your problem while still being able to use Pandas basic functions with a limited added complexity.

Comment: Interesting, if `return_list` or `memo_func` are slow, then it is easier to optimize the code.

Comment: This is strange this list takes 3 minutes to process while it takes a fraction of a second on my machine. I am wondering what could cause a 1600x speed difference. Do you only call `return_list(lst, 0, tolerance)` on the provided list?

Comment: Thanks so much.Yes, I only called ```return_list(lst, 0, tolerance)``` on the provided list, and it took me 3 minutes for the previous list but with your solution using numba it executed instantaneously.
But even with numba It's taking >15 mins if the length of the list is >35 .i.e if
``` lst=[-1572.35,-76.16,-261.1,-7732.0,-1634.0,-52082.42,-3974.15,
-801.65,-30192.79,-671.98,-73.06,-47.72,57.96,-511.18,-391.87,--4145.0,-1008.61,
-17.53,-17.53,-1471.08,-119.26,-2269.7,-2709,-182939.59,--19.48,-516,-6875.75,-138770.16,-71.11,-295.84,-348.09,-3460.71,-704.01,-678,-632.15,-21478.76]

Comment: Do you think it's possible to further optimize the return_list and memo_func using numba or any of the other libraries?

Comment: Indeed, I assumed that the size of the list was relatively small. The number of calls grow exponentially with the number of items in the list. This is why it is slow with bigger lists. Numba or other libraries cannot solve this. This is an algorithmic problem. I am not sure memoization would help here in the Numba version because the compiler should perform a tail call optimization and the values should be quite different for the recursive calls. That being said, I think the algorithm can be still improved though it is certainly not trivial to improve it. I will take a look.

Comment: And what if you first sort all the numbers in the list_numbers in ascending order. Then start just left of the center, add a number to the right if the sum of the selected numbers is negative and a number to the left if the sum is positive. Then check everything after adding a number if you can end up within the accepted bounds if you delete one number from the selection.

Comment: Your title says "count", but then your code actually doesn't just count but computes lists. Which one is it? Mere counting can be done more simply and efficiently. What do you actually need? And do your numbers always have two fractional digits or sometimes more? If just two, then it's both more accurate and faster to multiply by 100 and work with the ints.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Oh, I just realized it was you who changed the title like that. Can you tell why? I see nothing about counting anywhere else in the question or comments.

Comment: @KellyBundy It was because the OP provided new informations showing that the problem was actually mainly `memo_func` and not really the Pandas part and I found the last title was unclear, too long and not related to this new main issue. `memo_func` is a dynamic programming function that count the number of value in a given tolerance (accumulated in `c`). The function is called for each item of a list and the fact that the lists are in a Pandas dataframe are not very important in the end (the OP just need a foreach).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Hmm, I much agree about Pandas being unimportant, but I think `memo_func` is just a helper function and `return_list` is what the question is really about. And `memo_func`, with the parameters it has and how it expects to be called, really only works well as a helper for that `return_list`. Also, it doesn't actually need to count, returning a `bool` would suffice. I wrote a few solutions myself, not sure whether/how they'd fit into this now. I don't like how `return_list` works, so I don't want to implement a better `memo_func` helper.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Step 1: using Numba

Based on the comments, it appear that `memo_func` is the main bottleneck. You can use Numba to speed up its execution. Numba compile the Python code to a native one thanks to a just-in-time (JIT) compiler. The JIT is able to perform tail-call optimizations and native function calls are significantly faster than the one of CPython. Here is an example:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('(float64[::1], int64, float64, float64)')
def memo_func(original_arr, i, target_sum, tolerance):
    if i >= len(original_arr):
        if -tolerance <= target_sum <= tolerance:
            return 1
        return 0
    c = memo_func(original_arr, i + 1, target_sum, tolerance)
    c += memo_func(original_arr, i + 1, target_sum - original_arr[i], tolerance)
    return c

@nb.njit('(float64[::1], float64, float64)')
def return_list(original_arr, target_sum, tolerance):
    sublist = []
    for i, x in enumerate(original_arr):
        if memo_func(original_arr, np.int64(i + 1), target_sum - x,tolerance) > 0:
            sublist.append(x)
            target_sum -= x
    return sublist
```

Using memoization does not seems to speed up the result and this is a bit cumbersome to implement in Numba. In fact, there are much better ways to improve the algorithm.

Note that you need to convert the lists in Numpy array before calling the functions:

```py
lst = [-850.85,-856.05,-734.09,5549.63,77.59,-39.73,23.63,13.93,-6455.54,-417.07,176.72,-570.41,3621.89,-233.47,-471.54,-30.33,-941.49,-1014.6,1614.5]
result = return_list(np.array(lst, np.float64), 0, tolerance)
```

---

### Step 2: tail call optimization

Calling many function to compute the right part of the input list is not efficient. The JIT is able to reduce the number of all but it is not able to completely remove them. You can unroll all the call when the depth of the tail calls is big. For example, when there is 6 items to compute, you can use this following code:

```py
if n-i == 6:
    c = 0
    s0 = target_sum
    v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 = original_arr[i:]
    for s1 in (s0, s0 - v0):
        for s2 in (s1, s1 - v1):
            for s3 in (s2, s2 - v2):
                for s4 in (s3, s3 - v3):
                    for s5 in (s4, s4 - v4):
                        for s6 in (s5, s5 - v5):
                            c += np.int64(-tolerance <= s6 <= tolerance)
    return c
```

This is pretty ugly but far more efficient since the JIT is able to unroll all the loop and produce a very fast code. Still, this is not enough for large lists.

---

### Step 3: better algorithm

For large input lists, the problem is the **exponential complexity of the algorithm**. The thing is this problem looks really like a relaxed variant of [subset-sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) which is known to be [**NP-complete**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness). Such class of algorithm is known to be very hard to solve. The best exact practical algorithms known so far to solve NP-complete problem are exponential. Put it shortly, this means that for any sufficiently large input, there is no known algorithm capable of finding an exact solution in a reasonable time (eg. less than the lifetime of a human).

That being said, there are heuristics and strategies to improve the complexity of the current algorithm. One efficient approach is to use a [**meet-in-the-middle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Meet-in-the-middle) algorithm. When applied to your use-case, the idea is to generate a large set of target sums, then sort them, and then use a binary search to find the number of matching values. This is possible here since `-tolerance <= target_sum <= tolerance` where `target_sum = partial_sum1 + partial_sum2` is equivalent to `-tolerance + partial_sum2 <= partial_sum1 <= tolerance + partial_sum2`.

The resulting code is unfortunately quite big and not trivial, but this is certainly the cost to pay for trying to solve efficiently a complex problem like this one. Here it is:

```py
# Generate all the target sums based on in_arr and put the result in out_sum
@nb.njit('(float64[::1], float64[::1], float64)', cache=True)
def gen_all_comb(in_arr, out_sum, target_sum):
    assert in_arr.size >= 6
    if in_arr.size == 6:
        assert out_sum.size == 64
        v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 = in_arr
        s0 = target_sum
        cur = 0
        for s1 in (s0, s0 - v0):
            for s2 in (s1, s1 - v1):
                for s3 in (s2, s2 - v2):
                    for s4 in (s3, s3 - v3):
                        for s5 in (s4, s4 - v4):
                            for s6 in (s5, s5 - v5):
                                out_sum[cur] = s6
                                cur += 1
    else:
        assert out_sum.size % 2 == 0
        mid = out_sum.size // 2
        gen_all_comb(in_arr[1:], out_sum[:mid], target_sum)
        gen_all_comb(in_arr[1:], out_sum[mid:], target_sum - in_arr[0])

# Find the number of item in sorted_arr where:
# lower_bound <= item <= upper_bound
@nb.njit('(float64[::1], float64, float64)', cache=True)
def count_between(sorted_arr, lower_bound, upper_bound):
    assert lower_bound <= upper_bound
    lo_pos = np.searchsorted(sorted_arr, lower_bound, side='left')
    hi_pos = np.searchsorted(sorted_arr, upper_bound, side='right')
    return hi_pos - lo_pos

# Count all the target sums in:
# -tolerance <= all_target_sums(in_arr,sorted_target_sums)-s0 <= tolerance
@nb.njit('(float64[::1], float64[::1], float64, float64)', cache=True)
def multi_search(in_arr, sorted_target_sums, tolerance, s0):
    assert in_arr.size >= 6
    if in_arr.size == 6:
        v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 = in_arr
        c = 0
        for s1 in (s0, s0 + v0):
            for s2 in (s1, s1 + v1):
                for s3 in (s2, s2 + v2):
                    for s4 in (s3, s3 + v3):
                        for s5 in (s4, s4 + v4):
                            for s6 in (s5, s5 + v5):
                                lo = -tolerance + s6
                                hi = tolerance + s6
                                c += count_between(sorted_target_sums, lo, hi)
        return c
    else:
        c = multi_search(in_arr[1:], sorted_target_sums, tolerance, s0)
        c += multi_search(in_arr[1:], sorted_target_sums, tolerance, s0 + in_arr[0])
        return c

@nb.njit('(float64[::1], int64, float64, float64)', cache=True)
def memo_func(original_arr, i, target_sum, tolerance):
    n = original_arr.size
    remaining = n - i
    tail_size = min(max(remaining//2, 7), 16)

    # Tail call: for very small list (trivial case)
    if remaining <= 0:
        return np.int64(-tolerance <= target_sum <= tolerance)

    # Tail call: for big lists (better algorithm)
    elif remaining >= tail_size*2:
        partial_sums = np.empty(2**tail_size, dtype=np.float64)
        gen_all_comb(original_arr[-tail_size:], partial_sums, target_sum)
        partial_sums.sort()
        return multi_search(original_arr[-remaining:-tail_size], partial_sums, tolerance, 0.0)

    # Tail call: for medium-sized list (unrolling)
    elif remaining == 6:
        c = 0
        s0 = target_sum
        v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 = original_arr[i:]
        for s1 in (s0, s0 - v0):
            for s2 in (s1, s1 - v1):
                for s3 in (s2, s2 - v2):
                    for s4 in (s3, s3 - v3):
                        for s5 in (s4, s4 - v4):
                            for s6 in (s5, s5 - v5):
                                c += np.int64(-tolerance <= s6 <= tolerance)
        return c

    # Recursion
    c = memo_func(original_arr, i + 1, target_sum, tolerance)
    c += memo_func(original_arr, i + 1, target_sum - original_arr[i], tolerance)
    return c

@nb.njit('(float64[::1], float64, float64)', cache=True)
def return_list(original_arr, target_sum, tolerance):
    sublist = []
    for i, x in enumerate(original_arr):
        if memo_func(original_arr, np.int64(i + 1), target_sum - x,tolerance) > 0:
            sublist.append(x)
            target_sum -= x
    return sublist
```

Note that the code takes few seconds to compile since it is quite big. The cache should help not to recompile it every time.

---

### Step 4: even better algorithm

The previous code count the number of matching values (the value stored in `c`). This is not needed since we just want to know if 1 value exists (ie. `memo_func(...) > 0`). As a result, we can return a boolean to define if a value has been found and optimize the algorithm so to directly return `True` when some early solutions are found. Big parts of the exploration tree can be skipped with this method (which is particularly efficient when there are many possible solutions like on random arrays).

Another optimization is then to perform only one binary search (instead of two) and check before if the searched values can be found in the min-max range of the sorted array (so to skip this trivial case before applying the expensive binary search). This is possible because of the previous optimization.

A final optimization is to early discard a part the exploration tree when the values generated by `multi_search` are so small/big that we can be sure there is no need to perform a binary search. This can be done by computing a pessimistic over-approximation of the searched values. This is especially useful in pathological cases that have almost no solutions.

Here is the **final implementation**:

```py
@nb.njit('(float64[::1], float64[::1], float64)', cache=True)
def gen_all_comb(in_arr, out_sum, target_sum):
    assert in_arr.size >= 6
    if in_arr.size == 6:
        assert out_sum.size == 64
        v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 = in_arr
        s0 = target_sum
        cur = 0
        for s1 in (s0, s0 - v0):
            for s2 in (s1, s1 - v1):
                for s3 in (s2, s2 - v2):
                    for s4 in (s3, s3 - v3):
                        for s5 in (s4, s4 - v4):
                            for s6 in (s5, s5 - v5):
                                out_sum[cur] = s6
                                cur += 1
    else:
        assert out_sum.size % 2 == 0
        mid = out_sum.size // 2
        gen_all_comb(in_arr[1:], out_sum[:mid], target_sum)
        gen_all_comb(in_arr[1:], out_sum[mid:], target_sum - in_arr[0])

# Find the number of item in sorted_arr where:
# lower_bound <= item <= upper_bound
@nb.njit('(float64[::1], float64, float64)', cache=True)
def has_items_between(sorted_arr, lower_bound, upper_bound):
    if upper_bound < sorted_arr[0] or sorted_arr[sorted_arr.size-1] < lower_bound:
        return False
    lo_pos = np.searchsorted(sorted_arr, lower_bound, side='left')
    return lo_pos < sorted_arr.size and sorted_arr[lo_pos] <= upper_bound

# Count all the target sums in:
# -tolerance <= all_target_sums(in_arr,sorted_target_sums)-s0 <= tolerance
@nb.njit('(float64[::1], float64[::1], float64, float64)', cache=True)
def multi_search(in_arr, sorted_target_sums, tolerance, s0):
    assert in_arr.size >= 6
    if in_arr.size == 6:
        v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 = in_arr
        x3, x4, x5 = min(v3, 0), min(v4, 0), min(v5, 0)
        y3, y4, y5 = max(v3, 0), max(v4, 0), max(v5, 0)
        mini = sorted_target_sums[0]
        maxi = sorted_target_sums[sorted_target_sums.size-1]

        for s1 in (s0, s0 + v0):
            for s2 in (s1, s1 + v1):
                for s3 in (s2, s2 + v2):
                    # Prune the exploration tree early if a 
                    # larger range cannot be found.
                    lo = s3 + (x3 + x4 + x5 - tolerance)
                    hi = s3 + (y3 + y4 + y5 + tolerance)
                    if hi < mini or maxi < lo:
                        continue

                    for s4 in (s3, s3 + v3):
                        for s5 in (s4, s4 + v4):
                            for s6 in (s5, s5 + v5):
                                lo = -tolerance + s6
                                hi = tolerance + s6
                                if has_items_between(sorted_target_sums, lo, hi):
                                    return True
        return False
    return (
        multi_search(in_arr[1:], sorted_target_sums, tolerance, s0)
        or multi_search(in_arr[1:], sorted_target_sums, tolerance, s0 + in_arr[0])
    )

@nb.njit('(float64[::1], int64, float64, float64)', cache=True)
def memo_func(original_arr, i, target_sum, tolerance):
    n = original_arr.size
    remaining = n - i
    tail_size = min(max(remaining//2, 7), 13)

    # Tail call: for very small list (trivial case)
    if remaining <= 0:
        return -tolerance <= target_sum <= tolerance

    # Tail call: for big lists (better algorithm)
    elif remaining >= tail_size*2:
        partial_sums = np.empty(2**tail_size, dtype=np.float64)
        gen_all_comb(original_arr[-tail_size:], partial_sums, target_sum)
        partial_sums.sort()
        return multi_search(original_arr[-remaining:-tail_size], partial_sums, tolerance, 0.0)

    # Tail call: for medium-sized list (unrolling)
    elif remaining == 6:
        s0 = target_sum
        v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 = original_arr[i:]
        for s1 in (s0, s0 - v0):
            for s2 in (s1, s1 - v1):
                for s3 in (s2, s2 - v2):
                    for s4 in (s3, s3 - v3):
                        for s5 in (s4, s4 - v4):
                            for s6 in (s5, s5 - v5):
                                if -tolerance <= s6 <= tolerance:
                                    return True
        return False

    # Recursion
    return (
        memo_func(original_arr, i + 1, target_sum, tolerance)
        or memo_func(original_arr, i + 1, target_sum - original_arr[i], tolerance)
    )

@nb.njit('(float64[::1], float64, float64)', cache=True)
def return_list(original_arr, target_sum, tolerance):
    sublist = []
    for i, x in enumerate(original_arr):
        if memo_func(original_arr, np.int64(i + 1), target_sum - x,tolerance):
            sublist.append(x)
            target_sum -= x
    return sublist
```

This final implementation is meant to efficiently compute pathological cases (the one where there is only few non-trivial solutions or even no solutions like on the big provided input lists). However, it can can be tuned so to compute faster the cases where there are many solutions (like on large random uniformly-distributed arrays) at the expense of a significantly slower execution on the pathological cases. This tread-off can be set by changing the variable `tail_size` (smaller values are better for cases with more solutions).

---

### Benchmark

Here is the tested inputs:

```py
target_sum = 0
tolerance = 0.5

small_lst = [-850.85,-856.05,-734.09,5549.63,77.59,-39.73,23.63,13.93,-6455.54,-417.07,176.72,-570.41,3621.89,-233.47,-471.54,-30.33,-941.49,-1014.6,1614.5]
big_lst = [-1572.35,-76.16,-261.1,-7732.0,-1634.0,-52082.42,-3974.15,-801.65,-30192.79,-671.98,-73.06,-47.72,57.96,-511.18,-391.87,-4145.0,-1008.61,-17.53,-17.53,-1471.08,-119.26,-2269.7,-2709,-182939.59,-19.48,-516,-6875.75,-138770.16,-71.11,-295.84,-348.09,-3460.71,-704.01,-678,-632.15,-21478.76]
random_lst = [-86145.13, -34783.33, 50912.99, -87823.73, 37537.52, -22796.4, 53530.74, 65477.91, -50725.36, -52609.35, 92769.95, 83630.42, 30436.95, -24347.08, -58197.95, 77504.44, 83958.08, -85095.73, -61347.26, -14250.65, 2012.91, 83969.32, -69356.41, 29659.23, 94736.29, 2237.82, -17784.34, 23079.36, 8059.84, 26751.26, 98427.46, -88735.07, -28936.62, 21868.77, 5713.05, -74346.18]
```

The uniformly-distributed random list has a very large number of solutions while the provided big list has none. The tuned final implementation set `tail_size` to `min(max(remaining//2, 7), 13)` so to compute the random list much faster at the expense of a significantly slower execution on the big list.

Here is the timing with the *small* list on my machine:

```
Naive python algorithm:               173.45 ms
Naive algorithm using Numba:            7.21 ms
Tail call optimization + Numba:         0.33 ms
KellyBundy's implementation:            0.19 ms
Efficient algorithm + optim + Numba:    0.10 ms
Final implementation (tuned):           0.05 ms
Final implementation (default):         0.05 ms
```

Here is the timing with the large *random* list on my machine (easy case):

```
Efficient algorithm + optim + Numba:    209.61 ms
Final implementation (default):           4.11 ms
KellyBundy's implementation:              1.15 ms
Final implementation (tuned):             0.85 ms

Other algorithms are not shown here because they are too slow (see below)
```

Here is the timing with the *big* list on my machine (challenging case):

```
Naive python algorithm:               >20000 s    [estimation & out of memory]
Naive algorithm using Numba:            ~900 s    [estimation]
Tail call optimization + Numba:           42.61 s
KellyBundy's implementation:               0.671 s
Final implementation (tuned):              0.078 s
Efficient algorithm + optim + Numba:       0.051 s
Final implementation (default):            0.013 s
```

Thus, the final implementation is up to **~3500 times faster** on the small input and **more than 1_500_000 times faster** on the large input! It also use **far less RAM** so it can actually be executed on a cheap PC.

It is worth noting that the execution time can be reduced even further be using multiple thread so to reach a speed up >5_000_000 though it may be slower on small inputs and it will make the code a bit complex.

---

Comment: What a great answer!

Comment: Do you know a site like tio.run or replit.com or ideone.com where I can run this? (I tried those three but failed)

Comment: @KellyBundy Unfortunately, such websites generally does not accept the installation of new package. Some provide a bash terminal but only with few MiB of disk space. I generally do not use them because of that and they relatively bad ability to provide good benchmark results. I saw a lot of people using things like Colab nowadays for such a use but I don't know much about such tools. Couldn't you use your own machine? (possibly with a virtual-env)

Comment: Hmm what happened to the bounty? It's been 2 days since the bounty ended, so I believe that's well past the grace period.

Comment: @tdy I was wondering too. This is the first time I saw that strange behaviour. I am wondering if this is a bug. Do you know what to do in that case?

Comment: @JérômeRichard You could try asking on meta.SO or meta.SE. I'm not too familiar with the meta sites, but I'd probably start with https://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @JérômeRichard replit.com lets us install packages, but with numba I'm getting some error about versions/incompatibility. I got your code to work by removing the numba-usage, though. I btw like replit.com precisely because it allows installing packages, and I like tio.run because I find it *good* for benchmarking. I think Colab has less stable speed, but I could be wrong, rarely use it.

Comment: It turns out that the *automatic* reward system does not reward answers that are already accepted despite being modified. The [documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) states: "If the author offered the bounty, and accepted an answer that was *posted after* the bounty was started, that answer is awarded the full bounty". Answer updates are not even considered. This is sad...

Comment: @KellyBundy Note that without Numba, the code will be much slower due to the huge overheads of CPython. This is especially true since the code contains low-level optimizations like register tiling which only make sense on compiled codes. I expect at least a x100 gap between two variants. Still, it should still much faster than the naive implementation.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yes, of course. But it allowed me to use the solution for correctness checks for my own ones. Without Numba it's indeed still much faster than the OP's solution. (I think it was a bit slower than mine, so I could run both on the "big" list.)

Comment: Posted one of mine now. Their big list seems to be a rare special case, as it has no solution. My random lists of that size with numbers similarly large seem to always have solutions, and I solve them in about 1 ms. Your solution *without* Numba takes about 4.5 seconds for them. Can you try yours *with* Numba and mine on my random lists and tell the times?

Comment: [`random_lst = [-86145.13, ...]`](https://xkcd.com/221/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `return_list` implementation based on Jérôme's "meet in the middle" suggestion. Solves the little list in about 0.4 ms, your big list in about 1.4 s, and random lists similar to your big list usually in about 1 ms (yours takes much longer because it has no solution, which seems very rare).

I build two sets of possible sums (actually dicts, to also store the values making up each sum). Each input list element enriches one of the two sets (alternatingly) and then I see if I can combine the two sets of sums to get a sum close enough to the target.

```
def return_list(original_lst, target_sum, tolerance):
    lower = target_sum - tolerance
    upper = target_sum + tolerance
    A, B = {0: []}, {0: []}
    for x in original_lst:
        C = {a+x: xs+[x] for a, xs in A.items()}
        try:
            bs = reversed(sorted(B))
            b = next(bs)
            for c in sorted(C):
                if lower <= c <= upper:
                    return C[c]
                while b + c > upper:
                    b = next(bs)
                if b + c >= lower:
                    return B[b] + C[c]
        except StopIteration:
            pass
        A.update(C)
        A, B = B, A
    return []
```

Random lists generated like this:

```
random_lst = [random.randrange(-10**7, 10**7) / 100
              for _ in range(36)]
```

As commented earlier, if your numbers actually always have two fractional digits (e.g., if that's prices in dollars), then I suggest to multiply everything by 100 and work with integers instead, as that's more accurate and a little faster (because you for example wouldn't work with multiple sums like 4253.8700001 and 4253.8699999 but with just the *one* sum 425387).

Typical output with my below testing code:

```
1.9 ms  correct  sum: -0.110  result: [-17489.17, 33550.32, -1898.06, 64466.12, 55653.94, -57200.19, -52118.92, -52410.8, 27446.65]
0.9 ms  correct  sum:  0.080  result: [34010.73, -39401.83, 36773.45, 61138.58, 51243.06, -31135.59, 37111.03, -8041.74, 40569.74, -29635.29, -62148.04, -90484.02]
0.9 ms  correct  sum: -0.070  result: [22201.98, 52401.69, -3461.16, 92830.05, 46254.24, -98423.59, -88542.32, -96229.72, 72968.76]
1.3 ms  correct  sum:  0.180  result: [-80413.12, -44471.52, -5537.78, 45432.75, -90559.4, 95678.58, -21166.82, -37986.32, -11002.64, 99771.13, -91224.15, 45102.72, 96376.75]
4.3 ms  correct  sum:  0.030  result: [-32294.29, -19809.25, 5683.2, 45075.83, 82689.05, 28122.72, -5427.62, -56385.17, -16832.65, -54576.03, 25631.51, -44559.78, 42682.51]
1.4 ms  correct  sum: -0.440  result: [28730.08, -78111.86, -90193.07, 65740.76, 55275.86, 25774.95, 89340.08, -79391.46, -95721.86, -10195.17, 97754.17, 55893.35, -64896.27]
1.7 ms  correct  sum:  0.460  result: [30284.05, -34948.85, -95034.29, 75574.27, -3877.27, 57366.19, 45065.46, -59499.06, -14930.04]
0.6 ms  correct  sum: -0.070  result: [25329.36, -33188.28, 26540.6, 46938.11, 53980.07, -75188.36, -1110.85, -43300.72]
0.6 ms  correct  sum:  0.350  result: [-20237.16, 67810.75, 55698.28, 45055.27, -29619.9, -39269.26, -79437.63]
0.9 ms  correct  sum:  0.360  result: [-29807.14, 62063.17, 74790.75, -80694.74, -29835.81, 3484.13]
```

Testing code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVTLrpswEN3zFSNVEZBwKSjqrRQ1lZKsuu4SRZEhJrEEGNlDL1F1vz0dgxMg97GqF/Fjzpw58yD1Bc@yWl6vR56D4tio6lAIjZ5U4iQqVhwKjQEgUyeOB92UdJYFV6zKuL9ygFYhX7iC9QgDTwOogzR1/QhZPEA2AWwJ8TdaQbJ/DW6HzpZLBS2ICsai@uBm7YwfW7QraPUiafcdngV0Mz6bUCAvtee/3h1QXQZvs1JNFIr/4Urzo6elQtq2vj8FEabiLXqpnhpMuMyEso47f8pulshtnX6sCUs/XUne4szq2wC7JNu/sb@cRcFJyoJYfn5G8qFaq8ZSrHtZnwrZJume0BM9vM14jfAbZf0LqY0oZDUlqZnW94dN2NRHhpxqM7z1Hd8GsHFG0ZK94@RKloCi5AJBlDWVFWg@WVPgwbxSd3VnVo610hwdZek4ZoozqRTPsOJae7pJA8iborAtocQriUDPg1gb1y3ZJeXufxxpG@zed8IYQf477b9pSNnRwNzp2E/kEqtJKMxkU6HXEpux36/TJox5W3BJokZFqHHBXVsw13FGyawhcu7pmFv4LYqiGOAL6EKczlhcSFqmOKNPBlKesUZzuMgGzJ4XkqF2TAYHkwGxnLgXR1Ze3y7zFRNz0t9Cs/W4pziaz78H0G0@fKVD9M6APrAvn/1@PjEyfTHj4d0S1TQ63Sc@/MENGj76e@vJ4geyWgkqtDsL4xxKTTWdgecRigYk8mEOMV/6wUjteBx7IcEo/wnU6iQj0ZKYFcyew2VuQpjZ6c0TD9f6rNzAnvzr9R8)):

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import random

def correctness(sub, full):
    if not sub:
        return 'maybe'
    lower = target_sum - tolerance
    upper = target_sum + tolerance
    if not lower <= sum(sub) <= upper:
        return 'bad sum'
    for x in sub:
        if full.count(x) < sub.count(x):
            return 'bad x ' + str(x)
    return 'correct'

target_sum = 0
tolerance = 0.50001  # slightly increased because you use floats
for _ in range(10):
    random_lst = [random.randrange(-10**7, 10**7) / 100
                  for _ in range(36)]
    t0 = timer()
    result = return_list(random_lst, target_sum, tolerance)
    t1 = timer()
    print('%.1f ms ' % ((t1 - t0) * 1e3),
          correctness(result, random_lst),
          result and ' sum: %6.3f' % sum(result),
          ' result:', result)
```

Comment: I am confused since I cannot reproduce the same output values of the OP function with your code. In fact even the size of the output list is not the same (smaller). I just copy pasted `return_list` and called it using `return_list(small_lst, 0, tolerance)` the same way that for the OP function (with tolerance set to 0.5 and small_lst being the one provided previously). Did I missed something?

Comment: @JérômeRichard Well, there are multiple subsets with correct sum. Since I operate differently, I'm not surprised I find a different one.

Comment: Well, after reading the question of the OP, I think you are right: the OP did not mention a specific order nor defined constraints on the output length. Finding any solution is less expensive than finding one specific solution matching with the original function. But if so why not just returning an empty list ? This is a valid solution since its sum is equal to the target sum (0 so far)... Nothing can be faster than that ;) .

Comment: @JérômeRichard Funny you say that, an earlier attempt of mine did have that bug of potentially returning the empty solution. It split the input into two sides, computed all of each one's subset sums, and then combined. I couldn't simply remove the empty subset from either side, because I might've needed it to combine it with a non-empty zero-sum subset of the other side. That drove me to come up with what I posted, where `C` doesn't have the empty subset but B can. At least that was the idea, let me fix that bug real quick now :-)

Comment: I added a new faster implementation so to better compete with your and added benchmarks :D . The new implementation still return the same result than the OP since IDK what was its intent (the initial implementation appear to find the longest possible list). It turns out that your interesting implementation is pretty fast for random lists and competitive with mine (+1). For the big lists with no solution, it is clearly not as fast though. This is mainly because a solution can be found very quickly on such random lists (due to the central limit theorem and chosen input parameters).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yeah, pretty much matches what I thought/wrote. For their big list example, I'm happy enough with my time, it's still pretty fast and the code is simple and pure Python :-). About their intent: remember that originally they asked to *"find the list of numbers that add to 0"*. Before you changed the title to *"count"* something, and before you now agreed that that part is actually just about a boolean. I think what they *meant* to ask was *"find **a** list of numbers that add to 0"*, as that's what they said, except fixed to match the reality that there isn't just one such list.