# Optimizing permutation generator where total of each permutation totals to same value

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, permutation

I'm wanting to create a list of permutations or cartesian products (not sure which one applies here) where the sum of values in each permutation totals to a provided value.

There should be three parameters required for the function.

1. **Sample Size:** The number of items in each permutation
2. **Desired Sum:** The total that each permutation should add up to
3. **Set of Numbers:** The set of numbers that can be included with repetition in the permutations

I have an implementation working below but it seems quite slow I would prefer to use an iterator to stream the results but I would also need a function that would be able to calculate the total number of items that the iterator would produce.

```py
def buildPerms(sample_size, desired_sum, set_of_number):
    blank = [0] * sample_size
    return recurseBuildPerms([], blank, set_of_number, desired_sum)

def recurseBuildPerms(perms, blank, values, desired_size, search_index = 0):
    for i in range(0, len(values)):
        for j in range(search_index, len(blank)):
            if(blank[j] == 0):
                new_blank = blank.copy()
                new_blank[j] = values[i]
                remainder = desired_size - sum(new_blank)
                new_values = list(filter(lambda x: x <=  remainder, values))
                if(len(new_values) > 0):
                    recurseBuildPerms(perms, new_blank, new_values, desired_size, j)
                elif(sum(new_blank) <= desired_size):
                    perms.append( new_blank)
    return perms

perms = buildPerms(4, 10, [1,2,3])
print(perms)
## Output
[[1, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 2, 3], 
 [2, 3, 3, 2], [3, 1, 3, 3], [3, 2, 2, 3], 
 [3, 2, 3, 2], [3, 3, 1, 3], [3, 3, 2, 2], 
 [3, 3, 3, 1]]
```

https://www.online-python.com/9cmOev3zlg

Questions:

1. Can someone help me convert my solution into an iterator?
2. Is it possible to have a calculation to know the total number of items without seeing the full list?

Comment: For the counting: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71527595/efficiently-count-all-the-combinations-of-numbers-having-a-sum-close-to-0) is a related question that solve a relaxed version of subset-sum (I am not sure your problem is simpler and so if it can be solved much more efficiently).

Comment: Thanks I’m going to take a look at the library numba now and see how much that improves the run time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to break this down into two subproblems:

1. Find all restricted integer partitions of `target_sum` into `sample_size` summands s.t. all summands come from `set_of_number`.
2. Compute multiset permutations for each partition (takes up most of the time).

Problem 1 can be solved with dynamic programming. I used `multiset_permutations` from `sympy` for part 2, although you might be able to get better performance by writing your own numba code.

Here is the code:

```
from functools import lru_cache
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations

@lru_cache(None)
def restricted_partitions(n, k, *xs):
  'partitions of n into k summands using only elements in xs (assumed positive integers)'
  if n == k == 0:
    # case of unique empty partition
    return [[]]
  elif n <= 0 or k <= 0 or not xs:
    # case where no partition is possible
    return []
  # general case
  result = list()
  x = xs[0] # element x we consider including in a partition
  i = 0     # number of times x should be included
  while True:
    i += 1
    if i > k or x * i > n:
      break
    for rest in restricted_partitions(n - x * i, k - i, *xs[1:]):
      result.append([x] * i + rest)
  result.extend(restricted_partitions(n, k, *xs[1:]))

  return result
    
def buildPerms2(sample_size, desired_sum, set_of_number):
  for part in restricted_partitions(desired_sum, sample_size, *set_of_number):
    yield from multiset_permutations(part)


# %timeit sum(1 for _ in buildPerms2(8, 16, [1, 2, 3, 4])) # 16 ms
# %timeit sum(1 for _ in buildPerms (8, 16, [1, 2, 3, 4])) # 604 ms
```

---

The current solution requires computing all restricted partitions before iteration can begin, but it may still be practical if restricted partitions can be computed quickly. It may be possible to compute partitions iteratively as well, although this may require more work.

On the second question, you can indeed count the number of such permutations without generating them all:

```
# present in the builtin math library for Python 3.8+
@lru_cache(None)
def binomial(n, k):
  if k == 0:
    return 1
  if n == 0:
    return 0
  return binomial(n - 1, k) + binomial(n - 1, k - 1)


@lru_cache(None)
def perm_counts(n, k, *xs):
  if n == k == 0:
    # case of unique empty partition
    return 1
  elif n <= 0 or k <= 0 or not xs:
    # case where no partition is possible
    return 0
  # general case
  result = 0
  x = xs[0] # element x we consider including in a partition
  i = 0     # number of times x should be included
  while True:
    i += 1
    if i > k or x * i > n:
      break
    result += binomial(k, i) * perm_counts(n - x * i, k - i, *xs[1:])

  result += perm_counts(n, k, *xs[1:])

  return result

# assert perm_counts(15, 6, *[1,2,3,4]) == sum(1 for _ in buildPerms2(6, 15, [1,2,3,4])) == 580
# perm_counts(1000, 100, *[1,2,4,8,16,32,64])
# 902366143258890463230784240045750280765827746908124462169947051257879292738672
```

The function used to count all restricted permutations looks very similar to the function that generates partitions above. The only significant change is in the following line:

```
result += binomial(k, i) * perm_counts(n - x * i, k - i, *xs[1:])
```

There are `i` copies of `x` to include and `k` possible positions where `x`'s may end up. To account for this multiplicity, the number of ways to resolve the recursive sub-problem is multiplied by `k` choose `i`.

Comment: Thanks for this answers I’m going to run some tests on these. The reason zeros are not in my solution is because I use zeros as the base or empty cell which will result in all zero permutations be calculated inherently. For step one is that all combinations that sum up to ‘target_sum’?

Comment: Makes sense. Step 1 (`restricted_partitions(k, n, xs)`) should give all ways to choose `k` elements from `xs` with repetition that sum to `n` ignoring order.

Comment: One last thing I just ran `np.unique(output, axis=0)` on both of our outputs and it looks like the outputs are getting reduced. I might not be understanding what np.unique is doing but if it's just reducing to unique rows then the output size should remain the same. What are your thought on this?

Comment: `np.unique` does not handle vector inputs. You could use `.drop_duplicates` on a `pandas.DataFrame(output)` or `set(tuple(x) for x in output)` to compare the outputs. There should not be any repeated permutations.

Comment: You are correct, thanks for all your help